# Sending a file via CURL in PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to send a file using CURL and no matter what I keep on failing...

```
$imgfile = realpath("../../vozila/".$glavna_slika);

$ch1 = curl_init();

$ext = pathinfo($imgfile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$di['image'] = curl_file_create($imgfile,'image/'.$ext ,'test_img');
$di['access_token'] = (string) $ad['access_token'];

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($di));
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$data1 = curl_exec($ch1);

curl_close($ch1);
```

The result I am getting is that no file is sent. It is sending a string instead of a file

Comment: You set the file in `$di` but then send `$ad` in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Typo?

Comment: @ishegg yeah that's an old typo, I forgot to edit that one with the latest code, ill edit the OP

Comment: what is the output you get ?

Comment: @motto this is the output
["access_token"]=> string(40) "a526ac6febd446c11dd" ["id"]=> string(8) "1195" ["image"]=> string(82) "@/home/website/public_html/vozila/5387617666.jpg;filename=test_img;type=image/jpg"

Comment: @OhHiDer any updates?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems in your code. First, you don't need [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) will take an array, so just pass your `$di` array to it. Second, `CURLOPT_POST` needs to be in the code *before* `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. So your working code would look like this:

```
<?php
$imgfile = realpath("../../vozila/".$glavna_slika);

$ch1 = curl_init();

$ext = pathinfo($imgfile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$di['image'] = curl_file_create($imgfile,'image/'.$ext ,'test_img');
$di['access_token'] = (string) $ad['access_token'];

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($di));
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$data1 = curl_exec($ch1);

curl_close($ch1);
```